# Angular Element - Set the Shadow DOM to closed

Tags: angular, web-component, angular-elements

When create an Angular Element with the default settings the Shadow Root is open. Does anyone know if it is possible to create and Angular Element with a closed Shadow Root?

Comment: I'm looking for the same answer.

Comment: My conclusion on this was that an Angular Element can't operate without an open Shadow Root because so much of the functionality is in the shared scope of the Angular application that created the Element, such as the injector. This is just speculation.